# How can i fix "Bean Error" in spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis, mssql-jdbc

I`v got bean error...

this is error code:

```
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'testMapper' defined in file [C:\Users\user\Desktop\workspace\SpringBootSample-4\target\classes\com\simplify\sample\db\mapper\TestMapper.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/simplify/sample/db/DatabaseConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sqlSessionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver 
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'testMapper' defined in file [C:\Users\user\Desktop\workspace\SpringBootSample-4\target\classes\com\simplify\sample\db\mapper\TestMapper.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/simplify/sample/db/DatabaseConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sqlSessionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver 
2019-06-12 13:50:03.183  INFO 10780 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-06-12 13:50:03.242  INFO 10780 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-06-12 13:50:03.320 ERROR 10780 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :
```

and this is config:

```
@Configuration
@MapperScan(basePackages="com.simplify.sample.db.mapper")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
        final SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        sessionFactory.setMapperLocations(resolver.getResources("classpath:mybatis/mapper/*.xml"));
        return sessionFactory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public SqlSessionTemplate sqlSessionTemplate(SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory) throws Exception {
      final SqlSessionTemplate sqlSessionTemplate = new SqlSessionTemplate(sqlSessionFactory);
      return sqlSessionTemplate;
    }


}
```

update-1 mssql version

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.0.jre8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

What's wrong with it ?
Thanks for your interesting !
spring-boot, mybatis, mssql

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml as well, to see how you're loading the MSSQL Server driver/

Comment: Check your stacktrace, it says "...Cannot load driver class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver...". Check if JDBC driver is available on the classpath.

Comment: Try change your POM scope for mssql-jdbc from `test` to `runtime`. So the missing class can be found when running app.

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove the scope from the sqlserver dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.0.jre8</version>
    </dependency>
```

You need this driver when running the app.